# Trigger tomcat contentType detection

Tags: tomcat, configuration, mime-types, content-type

I have an application that run inside tomcat.
In my app i have some static files that i want to serve with the correct content-type.

I've found that the conf/web.xml has lot's of already defined type in there.

But when i check the response of my server i have not content-type defined.
By checking the responses i mean that i look at response header on the dev tools of chrome

The issue is that i need these content-type to be detected and correctly applied in order to use the tomcat ExpiresFilter.

Does any one has a clue on what could be my error?

-edit

i just noticed that when the expires filter is not set, the content type is correctly defined

-edit 2

I just read that 304 response has not content ,so there is no content-type in theses response.

-edit 3

So my problem has nothing to do with ExpiresFilter.
The problem is that 304 response has no body, so no contentType could be defined.
But then the expiresFilter can't do nothing with response header.
And since my resources are in a restricted area , the expirations header are set the epoc.
Is there a way to bypass this ??

Comment: If the client has sent an If-Modified-Since header, presumably the client already has a copy of the resource and knows what type it is. A server reply of 304 says "your copy is the latest AFAIK" so the client can just .. do whatever it wants with its existing resource. Does the client *not* have an existing copy of the resource? If it doesn't, it shouldn't be sending If-Modified-Since.

Answer (score 0):

Use mime mappings to define the content types based on file extensions:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>abs</extension>
    <mime-type>audio/x-mpeg</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

**References**

- [StandardContext (Apache Tomcat 7.0.78 API Documentation)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.html)